# Have do i get 2nd equation from 3 equation 2 variable system answer?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

My teacher today solved this system of equations for us that consisted of these 3 equations,

```
1)  p0   +   p1   =1

2) a*p0  +  b*p1  =p0

3) c*p0  +  d*p1  =p1
```

, like this!

First he wrote this equation:

```
p0= (p1 - d*p1)/c
```

Second he wrote this equation(**THE PROBLEM**):

```
c= p1 - d*p1 + c*p1
```

And last was this equation :

```
p1= c/(1 - d + c)
```

He did it so fast without really explaining anything and only after lesson I understood that I do not know how did he got the second equation!

**Can anyone please explain how did he got the 2nd equation in his offered solution????**

Comment: multiply the first one by $c$ and replace $cp_0$ thanks to the third one

Comment: @Vincent if doing so I do not get c*p1! How can i get c*p1?

Comment: The first equation is $p_0 + p_1 = 1$ solve this for $p_0$ and plug it into the first equation your teacher derived. Then solve for c.

Comment: I am talking about equation 1), not the first on your list that comes later

Comment: @Vincent Thanks! Worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite equation 1) by isolating *p0*. Call the new equation 1a).

```
p0 + p1 = 1   ==>  p0 = 1 - p1
```

And rewrite 3) by isolating *c*p0*. Call the new equation 3a).

```
c*p0 + d*p1 = p1   ==>  c*p0 = p1 - d*p1
```

Now substitute the value for *p0* found in 1a) into equation 3a).

```
c*p0 = y - d*p1  ==> c*(1 - p1) = y - d*p1
```

Simply distribute and isolate *c* and you are done.